# VDI and Java Rulesets

Tags: java, citrix, vdi

We signed our rulesets jar with comodo cert. We pushed the java package containing the rulesets and java versions to VDI. We had lot of issues with making rulesets work on VDI.

We had tried many things adding certs adding certs to trusted.certs and pointing deployment.properties to trusted.certs. Nothing works. We get a "Application blocked by Java Security" error. If you go java in control panel and securty and press view deployment rulesets. you will see a message "deploymentruleset.jar is invalid".

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add a cert called USERTrust RSA certification authority to the windows trusted root certification authorities. We exported this cert from a desktop machine and added this to VDI. Our desktop admin can freeze this change. This can be accesed by typing in certmgr.msc in search. This issue was specific to our environment I hope this helps people with VDI and java issues.